# How to rename object key based on a string of both properties and indexes generated by JSONPath

Tags: javascript, object, jsonpath

Sorry for the potentially confusing question. What I mean is this:

I've been tasked to rename a specific set of object keys on a massively nested JSON object I've converted from XML. These keys are scattered throughout the nested object, buried under both arrays and objects. Let me show you what I mean:

```
const obj = {
    "Zone": [
        {
            ExtWall: [
                { Win: "10" }
            ],
            HVACDist: {
                HVACCool: [
                    { Win: "10" }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

In this case, I need to rename the key **Win** to **ResWin**. However, this tag Win is scattered across a nested object far deeper than this.
I'm currently using [JSONPath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) to find the path of these keys. For example:

```
var WinPath = jp.paths(object, '$..Win');
// Returns - [
//  [ '$', 'Zone', 0, 'ExtWall', 0, 'Win' ],
//  [ '$', 'Zone', 0, 'HVACDist', 'HVACCool', 0, 'Win' ]
// ]
```

JSONPath also has a stringify function which generates a path based on the paths array it produces. Let's focus on one element for now:

```
const pathStringified = jp.stringify(WinPath[0])
// Returns -  $['Zone'][0]['ExtWall][0]['Win']
```

Somehow, I need to rename this **Win** key to **ResWin**.
Right now my best guess is to replace the `$` with an empty string so I can access the objec for key replacement.
My goal:

```
obj['Zone'][0]['ExtWall][0]['ResWin'] = obj['Zone'][0]['ExtWall][0]['Win'];
delete obj['Zone'][0]['ExtWall][0]['Win'];
```

Any feedback or suggestions would be much appreciated.
Also, let me know how to restructure my question because I can understand how it would be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're ok using a library, so here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.3.11/lib/index.min.js';

const obj = { Zone: [{ ExtWall: [{ Win: '10' }], HVACDist: { HVACCool: [{ Win: '10' }] } }] };

const modify = objectScan(['**.Win'], {
  filterFn: ({ parent, property, value }) => {
    delete parent[property];
    parent.ResWin = value;
  },
  rtn: 'count'
});

const r = modify(obj);
console.log(r); // number of matches
// => 2

console.log(obj);
// => { Zone: [ { ExtWall: [ { ResWin: '10' } ], HVACDist: { HVACCool: [ { ResWin: '10' } ] } } ] }
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

The syntax is very similar to the JSONPath sytax, but it provides callbacks. The code could easily be generified to allow renaming of multiple keys in a single iteration.

Note that `obj` is modified in place. You could do a copy before modification, if that is not desired (e.g. using lodash cloneDeep)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace *all* keys with same name you can iterate the entire tree.
If you want to rename by path, basically loop the path drilling down until you are at the requested key.

```js
const obj = {
  "Zone": [{
    ExtWall: [{
      Win: "10"
    }],
    HVACDist: {
      HVACCool: [{
        Win: "10"
      }]
    }
  }]
};

var WinPath = [
  ['$', 'Zone', 0, 'ExtWall', 0, 'Win'],
  ['$', 'Zone', 0, 'HVACDist', 'HVACCool', 0, 'Win']
];


function rename_by_path(obj, arr_path, new_name) {
  var pointer = obj;
  var dollar = arr_path.shift();
  var key = arr_path.shift();
  while (arr_path.length) {
    pointer = pointer[key]
    key = arr_path.shift();

  }
  pointer[new_name] = pointer[key]
  delete pointer[key]
}


function rename_all(obj, key_name, new_name) {
  const iterate = (obj) => {
    if (!obj) {
      return;
    }
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      var value = obj[key]
      if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
        iterate(value)
      }
      if (key == key_name) {
        obj[new_name] = value;
        delete obj[key];
      }
    })
  }
  iterate(obj)
}



function rename_by_paths(obj, arr_paths, new_name) {
  arr_paths.forEach(arr_path => rename_by_path(obj, arr_path, new_name))
}

rename_by_paths(obj, WinPath, "ResWin")
console.log(obj)

rename_all(obj, "ResWin", "ResWin2");
console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```